# Oracle regex eliminate all duplicate words

Tags: regex, oracle, select

I would like to eliminate all duplicate words in a comma separated list.

I've tried with:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '1234,234,1234,1234,928,1234,123,1234,Abcd,1234,1234',
    '([^,\w]+)(,[ ]*[\1])+') AS r
FROM dual
```

It should return

```
1234,234,928,123,Abcd
```

But in fact it returns

```
1234,234,234,234
```

Also tried with `([^,\w]+)(,[ ]*\1)+` but with `'1234,1234,1234'` it returns `(null)`

Also tried with

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '1234,234,1234,1234,928,1234,123,1234,Abcd,1234,1234',
    '([^,\w]+)(,[ ]*[\1])+', '\1') AS r
FROM dual
```

and following replacements, even '\1\2' but none of them is giving the desired result.

Please, any ideas?

Comment: The internet is amazing, I found this oracle [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/628667) that explains exactly what you are trying to do, amazing...

Comment: Amazing amazing!! Thanks, it's a pitty that it hadn't exactly the same title as this question so I could have found at first chance! :P Anyway, could you place your solution? Cause in the thread I don't see that it will obviously solve my problem to eliminate the repeated occurrencies (I've also already tried backrefference with `'([^,\w]+)(,[ ]*\1)+', '\1'` but doesn't work anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the method you were asking for, but it still achieves the same result:

```
WITH DATA AS
  ( SELECT '1234,234,1234,1234,928,1234,123,1234,Abcd,1234,1234' str FROM dual)
SELECT DISTINCT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
FROM DATA
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
```